# Persistent state with the react context api

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to make a website on which users can reserve a stay. I would like for the provided information to persist in case the user refreshed the page or go back to the reserve page for some reason. However I am not setting this up correctly, maybe I am trying to mimick the redux toolkit too much but according to some articles on the internet and chatgpt it should work like this.Should I be saving to the localstorage and is that the problem? It shouldnt right? please find below the context, the component and the top level of the app where I invoke the context provider.

`Context:

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

const INITIAL_STATE = {    
        name: "",
        last_name: "",
        dates: [],
        user_email: "",
        adults: 1, 
        children: 0
};

export const ReserveContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

const ReserveReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_NAME":
        return {
          ...state,
          name: action.payload
        };
      case "SET_LASTNAME":
        return {
          ...state,
          lastName: action.payload, 
        };
      case "SET_DATES":
        return {
          ...state,
          dates: action.payload, 
        };
        case "SET_EMAIL":
          return {
            ...state,
            email: action.payload, 
          };
      case "SET_ADULTS":
        return {
          ...state,
          adults: action.payload, 
        };
      case "SET_CHILDREN":
        return {
          ...state,
          children: action.payload, 
        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
  export const ReserveContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ReserveReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  return (
    <ReserveContext.Provider
      value={{
        name: state.name,
        lastName: state.lastName,
        dates: state.dates,
        user_email: state.email,
        adults: state.adults, 
        children: state.children,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ReserveContext.Provider>
  );
};

Relevant code in component: 
const Reserve = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { name, last_name, dates, adults, user_email, children, dispatch } = useContext(ReserveContext);
  const [guest, setGuest] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const totaal = adults + children;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;

    if (name === "adults") {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_ADULTS", payload: value });
    } else if (name === "children") {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_CHILDREN", payload: value });
    }
  }
```

```
<Options>
                    <OptionsTitle>Gelieve het aantal gasten aan te geven</OptionsTitle>
                    <OptionsItem>
                        <OptionsText>Volwassenen</OptionsText>
                            <OptionsCounter>
                            <CounterBtn
                             disabled={adults <= 1}
                             onClick={() => handleChange({ target: { name: "adults", value: adults - 1 } })}
                             type="button"
                             > - </CounterBtn>

                                <CounterNum> {adults}</CounterNum>

                              <CounterBtn
                               disabled={totaal >= 8}
                               onClick={() => handleChange({ target: { name: "adults", value: adults + 1 } })}

                               type="button"
                               > + </CounterBtn>
                           </OptionsCounter>                     
                    </OptionsItem>
                    <OptionsItem>
                        <OptionsText>Kinderen </OptionsText>
                            <OptionsCounter>
                              <CounterBtn
                               disabled={children <= 0}
                               onClick={() => handleChange({ target: { name: "children", value: children - 1 } })}
                               type="button"                
                               > - </CounterBtn>

                                <CounterNum> {children} </CounterNum>

                              <CounterBtn 
                              disabled={totaal >= 8}
                              onClick={() => handleChange({ target: { name: "children", value:                                                 children + 1 } })}
                              type="button"
                              > + </CounterBtn>
                            </OptionsCounter>                        
                    </OptionsItem>
                  </Options>`
```

The number of adults and children increase but after refresh should stay the same but they are set back to the initial values

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.